# How to make case insensitive?

Tags: python, case-insensitive

```
int_string = input("What is the initial string? ")
int_string = int_string.lower()
```

How do I make the input case insensitive

Comment: Python? If so, add tag - also, explain "what doesn't work".

Comment: yes python, not case insensitive

Comment: What is "not case insensitive"? Case sensitivity applies *only* when comparing - and there is not comparisons in the code provided.

Comment: I'm trying to make whatever the user inputs case insensitive

Comment: @pst: What do you mean? `str.lower` works fine, and `str.lowercase` doesn't exist. That documentation is for the `string` module, not the `str` type.

Comment: insensitive means "not aware of others' feeling"...

Answer (score 4):

```
class CaseInsensitiveStr(str):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str.__eq__(self.lower(), other.lower())
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return str.__ne__(self.lower(), other.lower())
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return str.__lt__(self.lower(), other.lower())
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return str.__gt__(self.lower(), other.lower())
    def __le__(self, other):
        return str.__le__(self.lower(), other.lower())
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return str.__ge__(self.lower(), other.lower())

int_string = CaseInsensitiveStr(input("What is the initial string? "))
```

If you don't like all the repetitive code, you can utilise `total_ordering` to fill in some of the methods like this.

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class CaseInsensitiveMixin(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str.__eq__(self.lower(), other.lower())
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return str.__lt__(self.lower(), other.lower())

class CaseInsensitiveStr(CaseInsensitiveMixin, str):
    pass
```

Testcases:

```
s = CaseInsensitiveStr("Foo")
assert s == "foo"
assert s == "FOO"
assert s > "bar"
assert s > "BAR"
assert s < "ZAB"
assert s < "ZAB"
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to `input()` function as stated [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)

> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not
> syntactically valid, a `SyntaxError` will be raised. Other exceptions
> may be raised if there is an error  during evaluation.
>
> Consider using the `raw_input()` function for general input from users.

So simply use `raw_input()` and the everything works fine

Comment: Assuming OP is using Python2