# How to compare string case insensitive

Tags: python-3.x, text, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

So guys i'am trying to make a dictionary app. I want it to be case-insensitive. Firstly i saw some solutions for this promblem but non of them suited with me. Let me explain it with an example: Let's say i have the word `School` my code works fine when i search it like `School` but it doesn't work when i search it like `school`.

i really didn't get this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/15400311/9692934

```
    key_to_search = input() #not raw_input() since its python 3    
    with open("fileOfWords.txt") as enter:
        for line in enter:
            if line.startswith("%s" % key_to_search):
                print(key_to_search + " is in the dictionary")
```

I want `School` to be equal to `school` and `scHool` and `schooL`. But in my case `School` is just equaled to `School`

Comment: So it's not the casing of the *filename* you're asking about, but about how to compare strings case-insensitive? Then your title is very misleading as `open` have nothing to do with it. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i tried to ask that is there a way to only lower or upper a letter in a word. If the answer is no i am going to lower all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be case-insensitive, you can just convert the input and line into lowercase and compare them.

```
key_to_search = input() #not raw_input() since its python 3    
with open("fileOfWords.txt") as enter:
    for line in enter:
        if line.lower().startswith(key_to_search.lower()):
            print(key_to_search + " is in the dictionary")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply call `lower` upon your search string: `key_to_search = key_to_search.lower()` and save all words in lower case. Your code will be:

```
key_to_search = input().lower() #not raw_input() since its python 3    
    with open("fileOfWords.txt") as enter:
        for line in enter:
            if line.startswith("%s" % key_to_search):
                print(key_to_search + " is in the dictionary")
```